# Polymer elements leaking memory in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, polymer-1.0

While navigating through different sections in my application a certain amount of memory is always being leaked. This is an Angular JS application using polymer elements. I have tried to resolve this using various optimizations techniques in angular js but none of them worked.

I have even cleared all of the functions from my controllers, removed the dependencies of services and factories, clearing out references but none of them seemed to be working. If we restore to normal HTML elements I see quite reduction in memory consumption. So the problem is lying some where with the polymer elements only.

All the polymer elements appears in detached dom nodes while performing a heap snapshots. **Is there any way to clear the memory referenced by the custom polymer elements?** If yes how to perform the same. The `remove()` function and making `innerHTML` empty does not work. I also tried with removing `Polymer.dom(this)` child nodes, but still it did not had any effects on the same.

**Are there any best practices to be followed while dealing with polymer elements in regard to memory leakage.?**

Comment: Can you give an example of memory leak(with code if possible)

Comment: Was your issue resolved? I'm facing the same issue. Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No it didn't. I ended up replacing polymer elements with angular directives wherever possible.

Comment: Polymer has an open issue: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4954 regarding memory leaks on update if innerHtml